# Algorithm: Start two services in parrallel but run them sequentially

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two services that I would like to start in parrallel but run sequentially. That is, Service B would sleep while Service A is running and vice versa. These services call an external REST API which has a rate limit. When a service has reached its limit, it would go to sleep.

I guess a naive way to achieve this is have the services continuouslly poll each other's state but I can imagine running into a scenario whereby both services sends a `sleep`  state and tries to `start` simultaneously.

Edit: The services runs on different machines/jvm environments.

Edit: The rate limit is by ip address

Any ideas ?

Comment: Use a lock inside a while loop

Comment: Make use of barriers ?

Comment: Carefully read and understand the [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) section of the Oracle Tutorials for starters

Comment: @JimGarrison the services run on different nodes/jvm environments .. I'm not an expert on Concurrency but it's probably not the ideal solution here, right ?

Comment: Set up a proxy. Have your two services connect to the proxy, and let the proxy implement the concurrency control, so it only calls the REST API once at a time. That way you don't have to change code in the services, you just have to configure them to talk to the proxy instead. The proxy could easily handle more than two services.

Comment: @Andreas Sounds like a geat idea if the rate limit is by access token, however, the ip address of the proxy would be subjected to the rate limit of a single service?

Comment: You question just said *"call a REST API which has a limit"*, and your question said to sleep one service while the other service was using the REST API. How is that a "rate limit"? It's a concurrency limit. --- Anyway, if the rate limit is by IP address, why would the two services have to poll each other's state. If they are on different machines, i.e. have different IP addresses, then they don't need to synchronized with each other, now do they? Please clarify your question!

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure what's unclear to you. I'm calling an external APi which has a rate limit by ip address. Having two ip addresses means once service A has reached it limit, service B would start and so on. They need to synchronize with each other because I don't want to run them simultaenously, I could but I don't since they would just fetch the same resources.

Comment: @eosimosu Is this REST API public? Maybe there is a documentation about it? For example Google REST API also has rate limits and it could be solved by exponential backoff algorithm: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino ideal solution is probably some kind of distributed lock

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the API is polled every 20 seconds.

I would have the services send 'suppression' messages to each other -- make each service sleep for a random few seconds on startup, then the first to wake sends a message to the other service saying "I am calling the API, don't call it for the next 30 seconds", then poll the API, and if it has not reached the limit, sleep for 20 seconds, then send another message and poll the API again, and so on until the limit is reached. When the limit is reached, the first service will sleep for (let's say) 5 minutes, so the second service will no longer receive suppression messages, and will start polling the API and sending suppression messages to service A. When the first service finishes sleeping, it will look for suppression messages, and only start polling the API when it is not receiving them.